# Libgdx: задать каждому объекту свой sprite из масссива

Tags: java, android, libgdx

подскажите, почему так получается:
есть массив спрайтов:

```
  Sprite bucketImage, background, r1, r2, r5,
            r10, r20, r50, r100, r200, r500, k1, k2, k5, k10, k20, k50;
```

метод в ,котором создаю объект:

```
  private void spawnRaindrop() {
    Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
    raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 64);
    raindrop.y = 480;
    raindrop.width = 80;
    raindrop.height = 80;
    raindrops.add(raindrop);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}
```

и вот как я пытаюсь отрисовать спрайты ,в цикле

```
 game.batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);

    for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {

        for (int i = 0; i < sprites.length - 1; i++) {

            game.batch.draw(sprites[i], raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
        }
    }
    game.batch.end();
```

получается вот, т.е все мои изображения выводятся вместе,а я пытаюсь для каждого объекта выводить отдельно каждое изображение т.е спрайт

[image: спрайты не должны накладываться]

Comment: может так нельзя сделать или можно как-то иначе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверно лучшим решением будет использование класса Actor

```java
public class Raindrop extends Actor {
    private TextureRegion sprite;

    public void setSprite(TextureRegion sprite) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
        setSize(sprite.getRegionWidth(), sprite.getRegionHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        batch.draw(sprite, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

Создаем так

```
private final Array<Raindrop> raindrops = new Array<Raindrop>();

private void spawnRaindrop() {
    Raindrop raindrop = new Raindrop();
    raindrop.setSprite(sprites[MathUtils.random(0, sprites.length - 1)]);
    raindrop.setX(MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 64));
    raindrop.setY(480);
    raindrops.add(raindrop);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}
```

Рисуем

```
game.batch.begin();
game.batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);
for(Raindrop raindrop : raindrops) {
    raindrop.draw(game.batch, 1);
}
game.batch.end();
```

Comment: в данном методе,У меня создается объект
spawnRaindrop()
данному объекту я хочу каждый раз когда он создается менять изображение из массива

Comment: При этом Вы хотите доставать изображение из массива рандомным образом или как?

Comment: @ Master Flomaster
совершенно верно, в рандомном порядке.
  sprites[i].draw(game.batch);//данный вариант,просто создает спрайт на земле, я помню про setPosition, только мне же у объекта нужно менять изображение

Comment: Отредактировал ответ